# use readFileStream to read a changing file

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I have an application that streams data to a file, can I use Node.js to read the file while it's being streamed to?

I tried using createReadStrem, but it only read one chunk and the stream ended

Comment: instead of reading file file, why not read the data from the stream?

Comment: Unfortunately, the other application doesn't provide that, it only writes to a file that you specify

Comment: can you show how the file is being created and you were able to read one chunk?

Comment: I'm using asterisk's MixMonitor dial plan application that recored the call and save it to a file

Answer (score 0):

You could try watching for file changes with [fs.watchFile(filename[, options], listener)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) or [node-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-watch). In file change you could just read last line with [read-last-lines](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-last-lines). 
Although I'm not sure how efficient it would be.